# Authenticate an AWS SQS scaler in Keda

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-sqs, keda

I have a Keda deployment that I've been trying to get to work for about a month now. At the moment, my scaler looks like this:

```
apiVersion: keda.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: {service-name}-scaler
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    deploymentName: {service-name}
    containerName: {service-name}
  pollingInterval: 30
  cooldownPeriod:  600
  minReplicaCount: 0
  maxReplicaCount: 10
  triggers:
  - type: aws-sqs-queue
    authenticationRef:
      name: keda-trigger-authentication
    metadata:
      queueURL: https://sqs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/{AWS ID}/{Queue-name}
      queueLength: "1"
      awsRegion: "ap-northeast-1"
      identityOwner: pod
```

The associated trigger authentication and secret are:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: keda-secrets
data:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: {base64-encoded-string}
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: {base64-encoded-string}
  KEDA_ROLE_ARN: {base64-encoded-string}

---

apiVersion: keda.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: keda-trigger-authentication
spec:
  env:
  - parameter: awsRegion
    name: AWS_REGION
  - parameter: awsAccessKeyID
    name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  - parameter: awsSecretAccessKey
    name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  - parameter: awsRoleArn
    name: KEDA_ROLE_ARN
  secretTargetRef:
  - parameter: awsRoleArn
    name: keda-secrets
    key: KEDA_ROLE_ARN
```

I understand that the `KEDA_ROLE_ARN` value is repeated here; I left both for debugging purposes. The order of deploying this is as follows:

1. Install common environment variables (this is where the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `KEDA_ROLE_ARN` values are stored. The `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` values are listed as `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_ASSUME` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ASSUME` respectively in the file and will assume their appropriate values on the container. Again, these are duplicated for debugging purposes. I would prefer to use these values rather than a separate secret.
   Install Keda pods with Helm
2. Deploy the keda-secrets secret and the keda-trigger-authentication trigger authentication
3. Deploy the container that should be scaled. This is where the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_ASSUME` value will assume the name of `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and the `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ASSUME` value will assume the name of `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and where the `AWS_REGION` value is defined.
4. The scaled object is deployed

For some reason, I keep getting an error from AWS when the scaler attempts to scale saying that there are no credential providers in the chain. It appears that the AWS credentials are not being sent. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show you two ways to successfully scale deployment based on AWS SQS

**First way : Using AWS IAM role attached to node**

If your IAM role (node role) has permission to SQS then accessing SQS becomes easier you just have to change `identityOwner: pod` field to `identityOwner: operator` so that KEDA can use node role to access AWS SQS

*Sample ScaledObject file with SQS trigger*

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: aws-sqs-queue-scaledobject
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: test-deployment
  minReplicaCount: 0
  maxReplicaCount: 2
  triggers:
  - type: aws-sqs-queue
    metadata:
      queueURL: https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/3243234432432/Queue
      queueLength: "5"
      awsRegion: "us-east-1"
      identityOwner: operator
```

**Second way: Using IAM user**

In this approach, we need to create below objects

1. Create IAM user in AWS.
2. Create secret in Kubernetes.
3. Create TriggerAuthentication in Kubernetes.
4. Create scaledObject in Kubernetes.

Create IAM user and give SQS permissions to this IAM user.

first encode IAM user Access Key and Secret key using base64 which will be required while creating Kubernetes secret.

Create **secret**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-secrets
  namespace: default
data:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: <base64-encoded-key>
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: <base64-encoded-secret-key>
```

Create **TriggerAuthentication** this will be used in scaledObject

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: keda-trigger-auth-aws-credentials
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretTargetRef:
  - parameter: awsAccessKeyID     # Required.
    name: test-secrets            # Required.
    key: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID        # Required.
  - parameter: awsSecretAccessKey # Required.
    name: test-secrets            # Required.
    key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY    # Required.
```

Create **scaledObject** to map keda with deployment you want to scale based on SQS trigger

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: aws-sqs-queue-scaledobject
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: test-deployment
  minReplicaCount: 0
  maxReplicaCount: 2
  triggers:
  - type: aws-sqs-queue
    authenticationRef:
      name: keda-trigger-auth-aws-credentials
    metadata:
      queueURL: https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/012345678912/Queue
      queueLength: "5"
      awsRegion: "us-east-1"
```